# Change background position in css doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I have an image with size of 5760x496px. This image is composed by three images of 1920x496px. Now i'm trying only to change the position with `:hover` and when i'll know how it works i'll change it in jQuery. The problem is that the result of my code is a white background so i think that something isn't working in it.
This is my css:

```
.slider {   
    position:relative;
    height: 496px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: url(../images/full_slider.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 0px;
}

.slider:hover{
    background-position-x: 1920px;
}
```

In this case i expected to translate the background from the first slide to the second slide only but this isn't the result.

Comment: What browser? `background-position-x` is not supported by Firefox. Use `background-position : 1920px 0` instead

Comment: I guess you need to use `-1920px` than `1920px`

Comment: @anpsmn it was right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can set the x property for background-position like this:
>
> ```
> background-position: x-px y-px;
> ```

Ex: `background-position: 40px 0;`

see this works with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/hboq09p9/

**code:**

```
.slider {   
    position:relative;
    height: 496px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: url('http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.slider:hover{
    background-position: 40px 0;
}
```

(I have just moved it 40px because my image is not 1920px wide)

Comment: Your example in jsfiddle helped me to understand the translation. I had to set -1920px instead of 1920px. Thanks very much. I'll accept the answer when 8 minutes will expire.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
background-image: url('smiley.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```